# Passing variables between PY and HTML using Flask

Tags: python, html, variables, between, transfer

Passing variables between PY and HTML using Flask

I need to pass a text input from browser to PY and back to browser.
But it does not work.

main.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        input_value = request.form['input']
        result = input_value.upper()  # Convert the input value to uppercase
        return render_template('index.html', result=result)
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run ()
```

index.html situated in subfolder template

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Program</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My Program</h1>
        <form method="post">
            <label for="input">Enter some text:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="input" name="input"><br>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form> 
        <br>
        <div id="output">
            {% if result %}
            {{ result }}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Below Input field appears {% if result %} {{ result }} {% endif %}
Screen Shot: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hv6s.png)
and submitting a value does not cause any reaction.
Please help ...

I expected:

1. That  {% if result %} {{ result }} {% endif %} does not appear
2. That input text is returned capitalized

Comment: It's working for me. Did you run the Python file or the HTML file?

Comment: I run the main.py file first and then I opened the index.html file. Found the error: After running main.py I enter now the address that main.py gives on the console into the browser and it works.